# Gamma Distribution MGF

Tags: probability, self-study, gamma-distribution, moment-generating-function

[image]

I'm not sure how to find part a, what formula can be used to find this mgf?

Comment: I found a general formula for the mgf for gamma distributions but i'm not sure how to apply the transformation to it.

Comment: If you know the definition of the MGF, you can work out the MGF of $bx$ from the MGF of $X$. There's a result about the MGF of s sum of independent random variables that I assume you know. Put those two things together.